# Deserialize JSON string into array of list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, deserialization

I've a string

```
var my_str="[(0,10),(1,15),(2,48),(3,63),(4,25),(5,95),(6,41),(7,31),(8,5),(15,2)]";
```

I need to convert it into an array of list. For example,

```
alert(my_str[1])
```

would give an output of 1,15.

I've tried the following:

```
var myarray = JSON.parse(my_str);
```

but it throws the error "unexpected token ( in JSON at position 1"

Comment: var myarray = JSON.parse(my_str);
but it throws error "unexpected token ( in JSON at position 1"

Comment: Add your comment section part also in to the question. Then it would be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this

```
var myarray = JSON.parse(my_str);
```

but it throws error "unexpected token ( in JSON at position 1"

So I changed the structure of my string to:

```
var my_str="[[0,10],[1,15],[2,48],[3,63],[4,25],[5,95],[6,41],[7,31],[8,5],[15,2]]";
```

That worked like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a strange sintax for delimiting inner objects. It would be appropriate to use "[" and "]" instead of "(" and ")".
Anyway you can easily replace them with javascript and make your structure an array of arrays of strings. Sounds a bit creepy, but this way you can create a licit JSON object and benefit of JS native methods.

```
var my_array = JSON.parse(my_str.replace(/\(/g,'[').replace(/\)/g,']'))
```

you can now work on *my_array* object and retrieve couples of numbers using array indexes

```
my_array[1] ---> 1,15
```

Comment: Yes you're rite, my syntax is not right. I corrected that n simply used Json.parse(my_str); thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `(` by `'(` and `)` by `)'` ,, then , apply `eval` :

```
eval(arr.replace(/(/g,'\'(').replace(/)/g,')\''));
//> ["(0,10)", "(1,15)", "(2,48)", "(3,63)", "(4,25)", "(5,95)", "(6,41)", "(7,31)", "(8,5)", "(15,2)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty naive idea, but does work (without `JSON.parse` or `eval`):

```
var arr = my_str.replace('[(', '').replace(')]', '').split('),(');

//> ["0,10", "1,15", "2,48", "3,63", "4,25", "5,95", "6,41", "7,31", "8,5", "15,2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = my_str.split("),(")
arr[0] = arr[0].slice(2);
arr[arr.length-1] = arr[arr.length-1].slice(0,-2)
```